# Trying (unsuccessfully) to get a DataGridView to reflect changes to underlying data

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm new to this group but have recently developed a taste for c#. Now I'm pulling my hair out with this issue. Have a winform with various controls that can change the underlying data. When a button is pressed I'd like the DataGridView to refect changes in the data.

I'm really struggling with this.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
namespace WinFormsAppReportsPortal
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    SqlDataAdapter myAdapt = null;
    DataSet mySet = null;
    DataTable myTable = null;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        InitializeGridView();
    }

    private void btRunProcessAndRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        Process.Start(@"\\fileserve\department$\ReportScheduler_v3.exe", "12");
        InitializeGridView();
    }

    private void btnALWAYSWORKS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        InitializeGridView();
    }

    private void InitializeGridView() {
      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["xxx"].ConnectionString))
        {
        myAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM WHyy.dbo.Controltb_zzz ORDER BY XLReportDescription", conn);
        mySet = new DataSet();
        myAdapt.Fill(mySet, "AvailableValues");
        myTable = mySet.Tables["AvailableValues"];

        this.dataGridViewControlTable.DataSource = myTable;
        this.dataGridViewControlTable.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Jason. FYI, this is a Q&A site, not a "group". We're a little different than you might expect. For instance, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts.

Comment: Just to start: Never use a connection in that way. Move it inside your InitializeGridView and acquaint yourself with 'using' keyword-

Comment: John - I'll keep future posts to the bare bones; I really enjoy using the site and would like to take part

Comment: What do you mean with 'various controls that can change the underlying data'. Do you write your change back to the database?

Comment: steve - is this to do with better garabage collection? could bad garbage collection cause the DGV to not refresh? Just noticed that the above bare bones code does actually work but if I add a further line of code which runs a seperate process that is when the grid will not update.

Comment: Steve - I'll expand the code to include what looks to be the problem- 2mins

Comment: Steve - the control button actually runs a console app that runs some excel stuff and then updates some of the Control table on the database - it's this control table that is in the DGV

Comment: Probably you are too fast. You launch the external process, but don't wait for it to finish, instead you run your query again. If you restart the app the new data is here right?

Comment: The external process at the moment is a simple test macro in an xlsx file - it finishes in 15secs and then the control table is updated on the databse. The winform is open all this time but the DGV does not get refreshed. If I comment out the Process.Start line then the DGV does refresh?!

Comment: Steve - I'll amend the code to include "Using" statement; doesn't seem to help though

Comment: Steve - should I have further nested "usings" for the adapter and the dataset ?

Comment: I can add a further button with just the refreshcode and that works fine - will add to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to call DataBind() on the GridView to get it to refresh.

So, in InitializeGridView(), after setting the DataSource try:

`this.dataGridViewControlTable.DataBind();`

Comment: Brian - it's not giving me the option of using a DataBind() method for the DGV

Comment: Is there a Refresh() method on it?  Sorry, I'm more used to ASP.NET controls, which use DataBind() as the trigger for building their content.

Comment: no Refresh that helps Brian() - I've amended the code and now the following line doesn't refresh the DGV: btRunProcessAndRefresh_Click but the following does refresh the DGV: btnALWAYSWORKS_Click. The process that is run involves a connection/adapter/datatable for the same source table - maybe that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

call `this.dataGridViewControlTable.ResetBindings()`  - for details including sample source and explanation see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f61k6akt.aspx).